How to define Logicaltype of JSON in Java parquet-avro schema
I have a JSON object which looks like this:
{
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2" : {
        "key3" : "value3",
        ...
    }
}

"key2" is also a nullable JSON object which does not have a fixed set of keys. The requirement is to define key2 as a logical type of JSON in schema and I am looking for a solution using avro parquet(1.12.0) in Java but cannot find a good example.
The schema should look like:
{
    "name": "Json",
    "type": "record",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "key1",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "key2",
            "type": [
                "null",
                {
                    "type": "string",
                    "logicalType": "json"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

How can I do it without implementing my own LogicalType?
I have tried converting with AvroParquetWriter using the schema above. I assume if things work, the meta of key2 should show logical_type : json when reading in pyarrow or other tools. But when reading the meta of 'key2' using pyarrow, it shows logical_type : byte_array not json.
Also tried to implement something similar to what mentioned in Avro Java API Timestamp Logical Type?
Schema timestampMilliType = LogicalTypes.timestampMillis().addToSchema(Schema.create(Schema.Type.LONG));
But it looks like java parquet-avro LogicalTypes does not have JSON.

There is no logical type of json in avro schema.
Probably, json-schema is a better choice here, instead of using avro.
But if you have to use avro, then specify it as a string, or implement your own logical type.
I think that a custom logical type here doesnt make sense. Since as far as the serialized field is concerned, it will still be a string.
Another option is to convert that embedded json field to native java/avro. For eg, your field2 could be a Map ?
